# Pyodbc - Invalid connection String- Login failed for user

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc, django-pyodbc

Im getting this error, trying to connect an external SQL Server from Django through VPN i tried different ways of formatting the string, but doesnt work.

'28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. (18456)")

The code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
import pyodbc


def stock(request):
    #ConDB
    password='eUHf?+adF6;w'
    server='tcp:10.10.45.1,1433'
    database='master'
    username='sa'

    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    template = loader.get_template('polls/stocks.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your password contains a semicolon so you must wrap it in curly brackets to avoid confusing the connection string parser:

```
... UID=sa;PWD={eUHf?+adF6;w}
```

Comment: i changed it, now i have another error.('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'. (18456)")

Comment: Double-check your credentials using a stand-alone tool like `sqlcmd` or SSMS.

Comment: And look in the SQL Error log.  Detailed information about login failures are stored there instead of being returned to the client.